# How to call a class method using an onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treegrid

So I have an init function defined something like this:

```
init: function() {
$("#editRow").click(function() {
<code>
}
$(".removeRow").click(function() {
<code>
 }
}
```

1. So, I was wondering if there was any way for me to call the class method `removeRow` in the onclick event itself? Essentially what I want to do is call the class method `removeRow` when my button gets clicked.

   ```
   var d = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger delete-new-row removeRow"><i class="material-icons md-18" title="Delete">delete</i></a>';
   ```

And whenever I click the button I get an error saying that `removeRow()` is not defined. So I am trying to figure out a way to call removeRow from pressing the button.

2. If I wanted to call `editRow` in a different onclick event, would I do it the same way as `removeRow` or would that require a different approach?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you adding rows dynamically?

Comment: sounds fun, what's stopping you ?

Comment: I have down-voted based on your question title which confuses me, as well as your under-specified question body

Comment: Do you want to call the handler bound to elements with classname `".removeRow"`?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a class"?  A class is just a label attached to a DOM element, it doesn't have any functionality that can be "called".

Comment: Basically I want to call the class removeRow which is inside of another function when I click my button, but when I do that I get an error saying "removeRow" is not defined? Any way around this problem?

Comment: by class, do you mean class method? the two are not one and the same.

Comment: you have not provided enough code.

Comment: Class Method. So basically I want to call the class method removeRow outside of the init function. And every time I trigger the button I want that class method to be triggered.

Comment: use instanceOfClass.methodName() inside of a function that you pass to the event handler.

Answer (score -1):

removeRow is not a function

you can use this instead:

```
$('.removeRow').click(function() {
  $( this ).remove();
)
```

For more reference: https://api.jquery.com/click/

In case you want to remove row on click of button:

```
$(<your-button-selector>).click(function() {
  $(<your-class-selector>).remove();
)
```

Comment: I already have a click even that looks something like that. But how would I call the class when my button gets clicked on? Because when I click on the button I get an error that says "removeRow" is not defined.

Comment: That's because there is no function named "removeRow". Classes and functions are not the same thing.

Comment: You cant call a html class in javascript, do you want to remove row on click of delete button?

Comment: I already have a function that handles that inside of removeRow, I was just wondering on how to access the class without getting an error that says "removeRow" is not defined.

Comment: You can't call a html class

Comment: How would I trigger this class whenever I click my button?

Answer (score -1):

you've forgot " in your jQuery. It need's to look like `$(".removeRow").click(function() {
<code>
 }`, and you're trying to access `.removeRow` which means you're targeting a class, so you need to add `var d = '<a> href="javascript:void(0)" class="removeRow"</a>` and then you don't need the onClick function in your HTML because if you're targeting the button class, jQuery will do the onClick function.

Comment: See, I did that but I get an error saying removeRow is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

Let me see if I understood your question.

You want to call the code that's inside here?

```
$(".removeRow").click(function() {
<code>
 }
```

To achieve that result you can 'fake' a click on an element of that class using

```
$('.removeRow').click();
```

Comment: I am trying to call the class method removeRow in an onclick event so I can delete the row.